# DataDog monitory query duration

Tags: datadog

I'm trying to screen for "if 99th percentile (over previous 10mins) of requests' duration is over 500ms".  But it's unclear if I have to do some arithmetic if `rollup` is doing sums?

```
logs("service:"/myService"").index(" * ").rollup("pc99", "@duration").last("10m") > 500000000
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what the query will look like in the monitor UI

[image: log monitor for p99 of duration over 10 minutes]

The rollup is defined in the monitor evaluation window, no need to do it in the query.